# django social auth with django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, python-social-auth, django-socialauth

I am unable to associate my social users with django.I created a CreateAPIView that takes token_access, token_access_secret and provider from  users.But everything seems to work.But do_auth method doesnt exactly create
my users social account.

```
views.py
class SocialSignUp(CreateAPIView):
# permission_classes = ()
queryset = User.objects.all()
serializer_class = SocialUserRegistrationSerializer
# social_serializer = SocialUserRegistrationSerializer
ee = None

def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    prov = request.DATA['provider']
    redirect = request.path
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        authed_user = request.user
    else:
        authed_user = AnonymousUser()

    backend = get_backend(name=prov, request=request, redirect=redirect)
    serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.QUERY_PARAMS)
    if isinstance(backend, BaseOAuth):
        print 'BaseOAUTH 1'
        # Twitter, for example, uses OAuth1 and requires that you also pass
        # an `oauth_token_secret` with your authentication request
        token = {
            'oauth_token': request.DATA['access_token'],
            'oauth_token_secret': request.DATA['access_token_secret'],
        }

    elif isinstance(backend, BaseOAuth2):
        # We're using oauth's implicit grant type (usually used for web and mobile
        # applications), so all we have to pass here is an access_token
        print 'BaseOAUTH 2'
        token = request.DATA['access_token']
    print backend.user_data(request.DATA['access_token'])
    print backend.get_scope()
    try:
        # if `authed_user` is None, python-social-auth will make a new user,
        # else this social account will be associated with the user you pass in
        user = backend.do_auth(access_token=token, )
        print user
    except AuthAlreadyAssociated:
        # You can't associate a social account with more than user
        return Response({"errors": "That social media account is already in use"},
                        status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    if user and user.is_active:
        # if the access token was set to an empty string, then save the access token
        # from the request
        auth_created = user.social_auth.get(provider=prov)
        if not auth_created.extra_data['access_token']:
            # Facebook for example will return the access_token in its response to you.
            # This access_token is then saved for your future use. However, others
            # e.g., Instagram do not respond with the access_token that you just
            # provided. We save it here so it can be used to make subsequent calls.
            auth_created.extra_data['access_token'] = token
            auth_created.save()

        # Set instance since we are not calling `serializer.save()`
        serializer.instance = user
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
                        headers=headers)
    else:
        return Response({"errors": "Error with social authentication"},
                        status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

my serializer class

```
class SocialUserRegistrationSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
     """
     Serializer to receive social auth for python-social-auth
     """
     access_token = serializers.CharField()
     access_token_secret = serializers.CharField(required=False)
     provider = serializers.CharField()
```

an other imlementation:

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):


    prov = request.DATA['provider']
    redirect = request.path
    backend = get_backend(name=prov, request=request, redirect=redirect)
    request.social_auth_backend = backend
    access_token = request.DATA['access_token']

    if hasattr(request, 'user'):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            user = request.user
        else:
            user = None
    user = None

    try:
        if prov == "google-oauth2":
            test_response = googleapis_profile(GOOGLEAPIS_PROFILE, access_token)

            # gender = test_response.get('gender')
            # email = test_response.get('email')
            # full_name = test_response.get('familly_name') + test_response.get('given_name')

            if test_response is None:
                return Response({'success': False, 'detail': "bad access_token"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


            user = backend.do_auth(access_token, user=user)

            print user
            my_user = user
            user_serializer = SocialUserRegistrationSerializer(user)
            return Response({'success': True, 'detail': user_serializer.data})
    except Exception as e:
            return Response({'success': False, 'detail': e}, status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I dont dont know how to make do_auth works, it always return user as None

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`django-social-auth` has been deprecated in favor of [`python-social-auth`](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). I think you would be well-served to switch and try using the extensive documentation provided for that project.

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but the problem is that I well be forced to upgrade the entire project.I am using Django 1.5, and a lot of third parties.

Comment: Ah, that's always fun. I'm sure you're already well aware of this, but Django 1.5 (and 1.6, too) are considered unsupported and potentially insecure. Sorry I couldn't help more in your case :)

Comment: check my edit, I added another implementation, but I still stuck with it.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the create_user pipeline step already included in the library?